# Spring Kafka cannot read environment variables

Tags: apache-kafka

Spring Kafka cannot read environment variables like `SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUME_PROPERTIES_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG`, but using `spring.kafka.consume.properties.sasl.jaas.config` works, kafka factory config is

```
public class KafkaConfig {
@Autowired
private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

private ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(ConsumerConfig.ALLOW_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_CONFIG, "true");
    kafkaProperties.getProperties().put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());
}
```

Comment: According to what documentation should that variable get read? You're misspelling consumer, by the way

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you want to set the value of SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUME_PROPERTIES_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG through consumerFactory() method ? Or wanted to read the value from properties?